# Is there a way to use EXPORT * to export all names in an ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, export

I've seen:

```
export * from …;
```

at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Seems I can export all names from an imported module that way.
But is it also possible to export all names in the current module?

So just something like:

```
export *;
```

This won't be the right syntax, since I saw it nowhere, but is there another way, with appropriate syntax?

I'd like to expose all names in a module without explicitly mentioning each in an

```
export (<large_list_of_exported_names>);
```

statement and without prefixing each definition of such a name with `export`.

Reason for asking this: I am looking for the best way to rebase the import system of [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org.%22Transcrypt%22) on the new ES6 import/export facilities. It is important that the generated targetcode (JS) is compact.

Comment: The general philosophy in JS these days is that explicitness is good. I agree having to list all the names in `export` is annoying, which is why I'd normally expect each individual item to be marked `export` instead. Any reason not to do that to avoid the repetition of the names?

Comment: Marking every item export is exactly what I'm going to do. It's a lot of extra words, however, in a language that's distributed on source level.

Comment: Technically true, but since most distribution is done with gzip anywhere, there's hardly any difference between `function` and `export function` I'd expect.

Comment: I've no idea how much time the extra unzip step costs on a page load. Any experience with that?

Comment: Not specifically, but as with most things it is best to measure yourself since it'll always vary depending on the size of the code and what environments you care about and such.

Comment: I will in due time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. Even `export * from 'other_module';` is only a way to re-export the named exports from another module.

Comment: Glad with this clear answer! (though I wished it was otherwise...)